# Сортировка методом простого выбора

Tags: c, сортировка

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10], b;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("a[i] = ");
        scanf("%i", a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++);
    {
        for (j = 1; i < 10 = i; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {
                b = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = b;
            }
        } 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", a[i]);
    }
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

В чем ошибка? Может и алгоритм тоже не правильный?

Вот 2 вариант, не правильно работающий...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10], b, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("a[i] = ");
        scanf("%i", a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++);
    {
        for (j = 1; i < 9 - i; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {
                b = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = b;
            }
        } 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", a[i]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alexandr Здесь правильно весь вопрос оформлять в виде одного сообщения.

Comment: Скорее всего ошибки в написание или оформление!
Вводить и выводить элементы массива стоит по спецификации "%d".
Далее ошибка в записи элементов, надо scanf(" %d",&a[i]);
Затем в for лучше оформить как: 
 
    for (j = 1; i < (9 - i); j++)


Comment: Теперь программа не выводит результаты

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка методом простого выбора сводится к следующим шагам:

1. Установить номер наибольшего элемента массива.
2. Поменять местами наибольший и последний элементы массива.
3. Оставив в покое последний элемент, выполнить пункты 1 и 2 над остатком массива (массивом без последнего элемента).

Пункт 3 повторять, пока остаток массива не сократится до одного элемента.

Вроде так)

```
#include <stdio.h >

main()
{
    int a[10], max, i, n, k, j;

    printf("Input n:");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ",i);
        scanf(" %d", &a[i]);
    }

    k = n;

    m1: max = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > max) 
        {
            max = a[i];
            j = i;
        }
    }

    max = a[j];
    a[j] = a[k];
    a[k] = max;
    k = k - 1;

    if (k > 0) goto m1;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

По крайней мере у меня работает ;)

Answer (score 1):

что-то вы сложно написали выше примерчик %)

```
void sort(int *a, int size){
  int i,j,k;
    for( i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
      for( j = i + 1; j < size - 2; j++){
        if( a[i] < a[j] ) {
          k = a[j];
          a[j] = a[i];
          a[i] = k;
} } } }
```

Comment: Почему сложно?) Наоборот, описан каждый шаг алгоритма, мне кажется все просто и понятно;) И если я не ошибаюсь у вас ошибка, последнее действие в пересылке, все таки, должно быть a[i]=k;)

Comment: Проект не компилируется и не выдает ошибок... Странно...

Comment: ой, поспешил вставлять, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот это тоже пойдет.

```
void sort(float *a, int n)
{
    signed register char i, j;
    signed char x;
    float temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp = a[i]; 
                a[i] = a[j]; 
                a[j] = temp; 
            }
        }

    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
        printf("%1.4f \n", a[x]);

    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Даже не разбираясь в деталях, бросается в глаза точка с запятой в конце цикла:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++);
```

И окончание работы цикла тоже непонятно:

```
i < 10 = i
```

Comment: i<10=i - что-то я такого не вижу, у меня программа запускается, но после ввода 4 элемента вылетает!

Comment: а вот оно: for(j = 1; i < 10 = i; j++)

Answer (score 0):

[Алгоритмы сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_сортировки) - тут описано много разных сортировок есть даже примеры на С/С++.
Но лучше все-таки использовать готовый qsort(), меньше вероятность допустить ошибку :-)

Comment: Да алгоритм то правильный, и реализация тоже... Странно почему не компилируется, хотя у меня работает как часы... Мож с компилятором что?;)

Comment: @psyhitus Правильнее вместо создания дополнительного ответа редактировать предыдущий, добавляя туда новое содержание.